# Iwasawa's results about relation between Galois cohomology and principal factorization

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-cohomology, number-fields, iwasawa-theory

Let $K$ be a Galois number field with Galois group and units group $G$ and $U$, respectively. How we can relate the first cohomology group $H^1(G,U)$ to principal factorization in K?
I'd try to find  Iwasawa's results in his paper titled as "A note on the group of units of an algebraic number field." (J. Math. pures appl 35.9 (1956): 189-192); but its PDF file seems to be unavailable.

Comment: "The author shows first that $H^1(G,E)$ is isomorphic to the group of ambiguous principal ideals of $K$ modulo principal ideals of $k$" says the mathscinet review.